# How can you make the $<$, and $\leq$ signs bold?

Tags: symbols, bold

How can you make the <, and the $\leq$ signs bold?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\begin{document}
$ \leq \boldsymbol{\leq}  < \boldsymbol{<} $
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: It doesn't look very bold at this point...

Comment: @PFM, No, just bold.